# How do you create a parent-child tree with table/excel data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data, diagram, microsoft-access

I'm using access to model a relational database. I have the following data in  a 2 column format:

[image]

The result should generate a tree/bullet point diagram that looks like this:

- A

  - B

    - C
  - D
  - G
- E

  - F

http://www.stepblogging.com/how-to-create-parent-child-category-tree-using-php-mysqli/

I found something similar in this thread but excel or ms access should have this feature built in somewhere

what's the best software solution to making this tree diagram?

Also, is there a way to abstract a tree diagram into the table data above (using basic .docx or markdown formatting)?

Comment: there's a post here from stackoverflow discussing the algorithm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444296/how-to-efficiently-build-a-tree-from-a-flat-structure

Comment: semirelated answer in json format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847131/generate-multilevel-flare-json-data-format-from-flat-json

Answer (score 1):

I solved, perhaps, slightly different case with tree representation on Confluence pages with https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GVIZ/Digraph+Macro plugin that can take a table as a source.

Comment: do you have a screenshot of what it looks like im reading the graphwiz link but still have no idea how its done

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the solution. it worked out for me

Specify the sheet you want as "INPUT"

and the output sheet as "LEVEL STRUCTURE"

Form is in `parent | child`, so if your data is backwards just swap columns
If its the top most node, put in `root` as the name for `parent`.

that way every cell in columns A,B have some value in it

run excel vba

SOURCE: https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/cascading-tree

```
Option Explicit

Sub TreeStructure()
'JBeaucaire  3/6/2010, 10/25/2011
'Create a flow tree from a two-column accountability table
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long, i As Long, Rws As Long
Dim TopRng As Range, TopR As Range, cell As Range
Dim wsTree As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find top level value(s)
Set wsData = Sheets("Input")
  'create a unique list of column A values in column M
    wsData.Range("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
         CopyToRange:=wsData.Range("M1"), Unique:=True

  'Find the ONE value in column M that reports to no one, the person at the top
    wsData.Range("N2", wsData.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
        .Offset(0, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTIF(C2,RC13)=0,1,"""")"
    Set TopRng = wsData.Columns("N:N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 1).Offset(0, -1)
  'last row of persons listed in data table
    LR = wsData.Range("A" & wsData.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Setup table
    Set wsTree = Sheets("LEVEL STRUCTURE")
    With wsTree
        .Cells.Clear    'clear prior output
        NR = 3          'next row to start entering names

'Parse each run from the top level
    For Each TopR In TopRng         'loop through each unique column A name
        .Range("B" & NR) = TopR
        Set cell = .Cells(NR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

        Do Until cell.Column = 1
          'filter data to show current leader only
            wsData.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell
        'see how many rows this person has in the table
            LR = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If LR > 1 Then
              'count how many people report to this person
                Rws = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, wsData.Range("B:B")) - 1
              'insert that many blank rows below their name and insert the names
                cell.Offset(1, 1).Resize(Rws).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                wsData.Range("B2:B" & LR).Copy cell.Offset(1, 1)
              'add a left border if this is the start of a new "group"
                If .Cells(.Rows.Count, cell.Column + 1).End(xlUp).Address _
                    <> cell.Offset(1, 1).Address Then _
                       .Range(cell.Offset(1, 1), cell.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown)) _
                          .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThick
            End If

            NR = NR + 1     'increment to the next row to enter the next top leader name
            Set cell = .Cells(NR, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
        Loop
    Next TopR

  'find the last used column
    i = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
  'format the used data range
    With Union(.Range(.[B1], .Cells(1, i)), .Range("B:BB").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23))
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        .Font.ColorIndex = 2
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 53
    .Range("B1").Value = "LEVEL 1"
    .Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("B1", .Cells(1, i)), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With

wsData.AutoFilterMode = False
wsData.Range("M:N").ClearContents
wsTree.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Related answers in excel VBA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821545/how-to-build-parent-child-data-table-in-excel

Comment: related answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821545/how-to-build-parent-child-data-table-in-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1